# Pass release version parameter to downstream jobs in Maven

Tags: maven

I'm a Maven noob currently working with Maven/Jenkins to perform some downstream jobs on the back of a release task and my team has hit a problem.

What we are trying to achieve is to pass in the version tag into the downstream jobs once the main build has been executed. We had been trying to achieve this using the M2 plugin, but it appears to execute in a **Build->Downstream Jobs->Release** cycle, and we need to have a **Build->Release->Downstream Jobs** pattern.

We therefore decided to create a separate job using the build step to perform the release a as a Goal. Here's the directives we are using to achieve this:

```
-Pdmt -Dresume=false release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DautoVersionSubmodules
```

A consequence of abandoning the M2 plugin for this job has been that the prompt requesting the version number is no longer appearing. Subsequently, we've been trying to achieve this via the Post-build Actions, and passing in pre-defined parameters. The issue for us here is knowing how to pass in a *dynamic* parameter based on the previously executed job.

An alternative angle we were looking at was specifying a properties file that the main job could tokenize prior to it's usage in the downstream jobs.

Does anyone have any advice on how we might achieve this workflow, or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, JFTR it looks like it's [outside of the scope](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/using-the-maven-release-plugin-things-to-know/%20maven%20release%20plugin) of the maven release plugin:

> To answer the question I had to enumerate some of the assumptions made by the Release
> plugin. I can tell you about these baseline assumptions and you can decide whether or not > something like the Maven Release plugin is appropriate for you.
>
> **What are these assumptions?**
>
> *Your codebase is going to be versioned and released as a “unit”.* What
> does this mean? This means that you are going to be releasing an
> entire project at once with all of its submodules. [sic] In Github it means that the Maven
> Release plugin is going to operate on an entire repository.

The complex relationship of the repositories, releases and resultant artifacts prevent us from automating the task in the manner described in the question